# Calling DoModal() from an event handler of property page does not bring the dialog pop up?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Currently I am working with property sheet in which I added 4 pages and where in the second page I added a button.Whatever the pages I am adding are being loaded from a resource.dll and when I run the application it work's as expected.As mentioned above that I added a button in the second page ,exactly this is the point where I got stuck.My intention is when button click happens I want to pop up a modal dialog box .Initially I created a dialog in the resource.dll and in main application I added a class using class view ,and the class is derived from CDialog .To get the pop up I added the following code snippet in the second page button event handler ,

```
Void CSecondPage::OnbuttonClick()
{
  CPopupDlg dlg(IDD_MYDIALOG);//CPopupDlg *dlg = new CPopupDlg(IDD_MYDIALOG);
  dlg.doModal();//dlg->doModal();//In this way also I tried but didn't work
}
```

and the constructor for CPopupDlg is as follows,

```
CPopupDlg::CPopupDlg(int n):CDialog(n)
{

}
```

And I even checked whether the event is getting triggered or not ,It is getting triggered but the dialog pop is not happening.

One thing what I noticed while debugging is as "CPopupDlg hWnd = 0X000000."

Can anyone please let me know why the dialog pop is not occurring and also please let me know how can I achieve the dialog pop when I click the button in the second page.

Comment: I don't have the details to tell you how to work around it, but I suspect the basic problem is that the resources are in your DLL and you are trying to load them from your main. You may have do add some code to get your main explicitly to load resources from the DLL, in particular, the dialog resource IDD_MYDIALOG.

Comment: Yes I am able to load the dll using LoadLibrary ,if it is problem with loading resource from dll then I should not be able to get the propertysheet up when I run the application right.Everything is working fine .But only thing not able to get the pop up when I click on the button in the property page.Same thing I checked for dialog based application then it is working ,but when calling from the property page I am not gettng the pop up.Details mean what details you exactly need .please let me know that so that I can provide you .

Comment: Should the dialog to be derived from property page,if so I tried that also but failed to get the pop in that scenario also.

Comment: MFC provides a built-in resource manager, that usually works out-of-the-box. If, however, you decide to move resources (like your dialog template) to a different module, you are responsible for managing the state manually. This is required so that MFC knows **where** to look for resources. The details are explained at [TN058: MFC Module State Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft1t4bbc.aspx). As a hotfix you can compile the dialog template into your main application module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,finally I resolved it .In the buttonclick event as I mentioned above need to set the resource handle to the resource.dll using AfxSetResourceHandle(),because in the first page I had set it to the bitmapres.dll I was failing to find the dialog resource in this bitmapres.dll,so again resetting it in the click event to resource.dll I am able to find the resource in the resource and the dialog which I was calling for the pop doesn't have that type(it is of WS_CHILD)because of this even though we set resource handle using AfxSetResourceHandle() it is getting overlapped .Then I modified it's style to WS_POPUP then it is working fine.

```
Void CSecondPage::OnbuttonClick()
{


CPopupDlg dlg(IDD_MYDIALOG);//CPopupDlg *dlg = new CPopupDlg(IDD_MYDIALOG);
AfxSetResourceHandle(hDialogRes);
dlg.doModal();//dlg->doModal();//In this way also I tried but didn't work

}
```

setting the style as follows led me to get the desired target.

```
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
```